# Is the key in ~/.ssh/known_hosts different from the ssh public key of the remote host?

Tags: ssh, key-authentication

I believe it is because at this point, the remote host has not even necessarily generated an ssh key. This phase is during server authentication, in which I believe that the remote server gives a public key to the client and responds to the clients challenge to prove that it is the host associated with that public key. But then what exactly is this public key? Is it different from the ssh key? The remote host doesn't necessarily even have an ssh key for this user yet right?

Comment: The remote host has a server key that is independent of any user keys. Most ssh clients will store the remote server's public key along with asking you if you really trust the key. If this key changes you will then be asked again if you trust the new key. Host keys and user keys are completely separately separate entities. For example, I have one user account that is shared across 300+ servers. When I ssh to any particular server, my client checks the server's public key. If that matches, it then checks the key to my account. [continued]

Comment: A server will not be able to start an ssh daemon without public/private keypairs being generated but these are specifically to authenticate the server. The user keypairs are used when you try to authenticate to a specific user on the server. Server keypairs and user keypairs are essentially used at very different times in the login process.

Comment: Related thread on Super User https://superuser.com/questions/421997/what-is-a-ssh-key-fingerprint-and-how-is-it-generated

Comment: Another related question in https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20706/what-is-the-difference-between-authorized-keys-and-known-hosts-file-for-ssh